# How to re-catch already caught exception in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a code similar to the following:

```
try:
    something()
except DerivedException as e:
    if e.field1 == 'abc':
        handle(e)
    else:
        # re-raise with catch in the next section!
except BaseException as e:
    do_some_stuff(e)
```

Where `DerivedException` is derived from `BaseException`.

So, like the comment in the code mentions - I want to re-raise the exception from inside of the first `except`-section and catch it again inside the second `except`-section.

How to do that?

Comment: I think you need to nest another try-except, because the first try-except will not catch again.

Answer (score 7):

Python's syntax provides no way to continue from one `except` block to another on the same `try`. The closest you can get is with two `try`s:

```
try:
    try:
        whatever()
    except Whatever as e:
        if dont_want_to_handle(e):
            raise
        handle(e)
except BroaderCategory as e:
    handle_differently(e)
```

Personally, I'd use one `except` block and do the dispatch manually:

```
try:
    whatever()
except BroaderCategory as e:
    if isinstance(e, SpecificType) and other_checks(e):
        do_one_thing()
    else:
        do_something_else()
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
{ ~ }  » python                                                                                     
>>> try:
...     try:
...         raise Exception("foobar")
...     except Exception as e:
...         raise e
... except Exception as f:
...     print "hi"
...
hi
```

Answer (score -1):

You just use the raise keyword alone to raise the error that was just caught.

```
try:
    try:
        something()
    except DerivedException as e:
        if e.field1 == 'abc':
            handle(e)
        else:
            raise
except BaseException as e:
    do_some_stuff(e)
```

Comment: But an error that is raised in one `except` will not be caught in any of the `except`s that follow it.

Comment: oh then you just need to add another try block around it